# MINECRAFT MCPE 0.11.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Umm how do I make a seed from my world like the numbers I tested it with my friend but no builds are in im just in the middle of nowhere I tapped "infinite" but well nothing happened I tried to look for videos of a seed with a castle (cause I accidentally deleted all my worlds) and it will take a long time to build an epic build again. so give me a seed with an epic build thanks for reading

Comment: The seed only determines what the world is like when *created*. (Technicly speaking, the seed detemines what pseudo-random numbers the game uses to generate the world. Same seed always uses the same numbers.) If anything is built into the world, it's not saved in the seed.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, that's not how a seed works. A seed is used to make the starting world but can't be used to keep any changes you've made to it.

What you are trying to do is download a map. Try googling minecraft pe download map- you'll get a lot of sites with premade maps on them.

Answer (score 1):

Directly answering your question: none. There is no seed that has a pre-built epic castle. A seed is just a pre-built world with some terrain. If you lost your build, sorry, you have to build it again.

Your question is off topic anyway. Sorry but you won't receive a nice answer here. (Or anywhere.)